# Broken Adobe Air Installers, Do I Need a Certificate

Tags: flash, air, certificate, publishing, signing

This is a multi-part question, but all to resolve the same issue.

I'm trying to publish a project I've been working on but get intermittent problems with .air files that are generated.

I always get the following warning when publishing my project:

"There was an error connecting to the timestamp server. You may not have a connection to the network, or the server itself may have a problem.

If you choose to disable timestamping, the AIR application will fail to install when the digital signature expires."

So I have had no choice but to disable timestamping.

I do have a working internet connection, but I'm working from my company network, could this be an issue, and if so, is there a work around (Opening a specific port or something)? Also, how long do the above-mentioned digital signatures have before expiring?

Also, I am creating my own certificate. Do I need to purchase some kind of certificate/license to install my application on another computer? I've done some research, but the information is hard to find, and what I do find is kind of cryptic at best. Currently, I only need to deploy to machines within the company.

Sometimes the installer works fine and without issue (on the computer that generated it at least), other times I get "The application could not be installed because the installer file is damaged. Try obtaining a new installer file from the application author." as an error message. Other times I get an error stating that certificates or signatures or something do not match (Sorry, I couldn't replicate the error so am paraphrasing).I have yet to get an install to work on a separate machine.

I've tried using Air 2.5 and 2.6.

Also, as an extra while I'm here: Can I embed AIR applications to be run INSIDE a browser like a traditional Flash project?

Comment: It's best to avoid asking [multipart questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things) on Stackoverflow.  Ask each one as a separate question instead.

Comment: Why aren't you using a normal certificate?  The whole reason there's a certificate (and Flash was blocked) is so that Apple can charge you to publish your app.  Apple allows your app to be tested on 100 devices - add the device IDs to provisioning profile, publish .ipa and pass .ipa file to user, they drop into itunes and install.

Comment: I'm not developing for iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About certificate, you can use a self signed certificate, the only difference is that the users will see a big warning when installing that the publisher is unknown.
About timestamping, I only know that the adt tool that packages the app is attempting to connect to a timestamping server, I am not sure what protocol is used, you will need to check this and unblock this.
If the installer is not timestamped then the issue is that after the certificate expires you can continue using this installer and need to do a new one with a certificate that is not expired.

As an example, if I use a certificate that expires tomorrow today and the installer is not timestamped then it will not work after tomorrow but if it was timestamped then it will continue to work after the certificate expired because it was created  before the expiration

I seen the installer is damaged erors a few times on our customers machine, usually on Windows, sometimes uninstalling and reinstalling AIR helped but not always, the problem is that the error message is not detailled enough to fix this, in rare cases I had to create .exe installers for those customers but I suggest to try the installers on a few machines first and use the native .exe installers if anything else is not working.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what the differences, pros/cons of using an exe installer instead of an air installer are?